# Matlab - Delete row in Cell array if value contains xxx

Tags: matlab

In Matlab how do I delete cells in a cell array that contains a varaible string. Say my cell array is

```
 'C:\svnTrunk\RadarLib\radarlb\utilities\scatteredInterpolant.m'
 'C:\svnTrunk\RadarLib\radarlb\utilities\unitize.m'
 'C:\svnTrunk\Simulations\GUIMenu.m'
 'C:\svnTrunk\Simulations\Maritime\GenericModel\CalculateOutputs.m'
 'C:\svnTrunk\Simulations\Maritime\GenericModel\ComputeBeamLayout.m'
 'C:\svnTrunk\Simulations\Maritime\GenericModel\ComputeBeamwidthOnGround3.m'
```

I want to remove all entries that contain a string varaible = 'GenericModel' so I'd only have

```
 'C:\svnTrunk\RadarLib\radarlb\utilities\scatteredInterpolant.m'
 'C:\svnTrunk\RadarLib\radarlb\utilities\unitize.m'
 'C:\svnTrunk\Simulations\GUIMenu.m'
```

Comment: you should check out 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because today's your lucky day:

```
A( cellfun('isempty', strfind(A, 'GenericModel')) )
```

with `A` of course your cell array.